# Using two Navigators in an app React native

Tags: react-native

Trying to use bar Navigation and drawer navigator in the same app, and now sure how to make it work.

So currently In the App.js I have a "NavigationContainer", and inside I have a "BarNavigator". whcih works fine, then I wanna add a "DrawerNavigator" inside the "NavigationContainer" then I got an error "Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app"

then i found this link doing exactly [what i wanted](https://dev.to/easybuoy/combining-stack-tab-drawer-navigations-in-react-native-with-react-navigation-5-da) ( showing at the end of the page ) and apply what he is doing. still got the same error, then I removed the "BarNavigator" which is the working one, and test out if DrawerNavigator got error, and yes. even got error with the DrawerNavigator only. and here is the code.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  //<HomeStackNavigator />
  <DrawerNavigator />
</NavigationContainer>
);
};
export default App;
```

DrawerNavigator.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
 return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
       <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={navigation_bar} />
       {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Ivestment} /> */}
     </Drawer.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Navigator.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const screenOptionStyle = {
headerShown: false,
};
const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
 return (
   <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
 );
};
  export default HomeStackNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

You should have only 1 "NavigationContainer" and the navigators should be nested, i.e. one inside of another (parent-child not siblings).

It should look something like this:

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
     return (
          <NavigationContainer>
               <DrawerNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
     );
};
export default App;
```

**DrawerNavigator.js**

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
     return (
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
               <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabNavigator} />
               <Drawer.Screen name="OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
     );
};
export default DrawerNavigator;
```

**TabNavigator.js**

```
const Tab = createTabNavigator();
const screenOptionStyle = {
     headerShown: false,
};
const HomeTabNavigator = () => {
     return (
          <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
               <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
               <Tab.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
     );
};
export default HomeTabNavigator;
```

Might be easier to look at it bottom-top as well.

Comment: Thanks it is wokring now, but now when I clicked the linked pages from DrawerNavigator, they are missing TabNavigator.

Comment: Because the TabNavigator is only in the Home Screen. If You want the Tab Navigator to be shown in all screens you should swap them. Make the Tab Navigator the main navigator and the drawer inside of it.